# Loop focus in RecylerView for Tv

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

according to https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation

> You should set up the navigation order as a loop, so that the last
>   control directs focus back to the first one.

I have tried to implement such behavior for `RecyclerView` items:

```
fun RecyclerView.loopFocusVertically() {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val children = getAllChildren()
        val firstFocusableItem = children.firstOrNull { it.isFocusable }
        val lastFocusableItem = children.lastOrNull { it.isFocusable }
        firstFocusableItem?.let { it.nextFocusUpId = lastFocusableItem?.id ?: it.id }
        lastFocusableItem?.let { it.nextFocusDownId = firstFocusableItem?.id ?: it.id }
    }
}
```

So on layout change i made first view have `nextFocusUpId` reference to last view, and the last view `nextFocusDownId` reference to first view. But it only works in case all views are actually layouted on screen, which obviously is not true in general case. `RecyclerView` actually recycles views, so last and first view may not exist at the same time on screen

How to implement focus loop for rv in leanback mode?
I have tried to use `androidx.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView` from leanback library, but it also doesn't have required behavior.

By default on pressing up from first focusable item of rv focus jumps to some other focusable view outside of rv, which is not so appropriate

Answer (score 1):

> By default on pressing up from first focusable item of rv focus jumps to some other focusable view outside of rv, which is not so appropriate

First, as for the UX, it's really problematic if you have views above your list so pressing up will really be an issue if to scroll to the last item as you want or to go to the above view.

With that said I'd suggest you give the loop option only from bottom in this case if you have a view above the list that should also get focus.

In general, I suggest you check VerticalGridView/HorizontalGridView for adding rows and lists in a lean-back app.

In the example I adjusted it to use a RecyclerView for your question.

For doing so you'll have to catch the button event, check if its the last item and if so, request focus to the first item.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
            if (onDownClick(event)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(ev);
}

public boolean onDownClick(KeyEvent event) {

    int currentIndex = 0;

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        currentIndex = mAdapter.indexOf(mCurrentItem);
    }

    if (currentIndex == mAdapter.size() - 1) {
        mListRecycler.scrollToPosition(0);
        if (mListRecycler.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0) != null) {
            mListRecycler.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.requestFocus();
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```